# Positioning an element within its superview

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa, nsview

So, this is my case :

- One `NSBox`
- Inside this, there is an `NSTextField`

What I want to do is :

- Programmatically manage to position the textField in the box (e.g. top left, top right, center, etc).

I've tried doing it with `NSTextField`'s `bounds` or `frame`, but I don't think I can make it...

Any ideas?

Comment: What doesn't work about setting its frame?

Comment: Did you try to override the `-layout` method of the NSBox and position the subviews manually? You might have to create a custom subclass for your NSBox to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, do you just want to make sure the NSTextField is always in the top left, center, or whatever, when the view is resized? If so, then you can use struts and springs for that. If you just want to move the text field, then changing the frame should work. Ex, if you have a text field called *foo*, you can set the whole frame:

```
[foo setFrame: CGRectMake(desiredX,desiredY,foo.bounds.size.width,foo.bounds.size.height)];
```

or just its origin (effectively repositioning it):

```
[foo setFrameOrigin: CGPointMake(desiredX, desiredY)];
```

Answer (score 0):

For interest's sake, there is also a minilanguage for positioning in Cocoa called [Visual Format Language](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Articles/formatLanguage.html).  It lets you specify relationships such as:

```
|-50-[orchidBox]-50-|
```

Which means the child element should be indented 50px from it's superview on each side.